# Infinite Loop While Modifying Binary File

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

I am trying to open a binary file read a part from it and then modify it but this ends up in an infinite loop.

*Things I had in mind before writing the program:*

1. EOF is a value that is returned by a function that reads/writes from/to the stream when End of file is found or if an error occurs.
2. File indicator will go the size of the bytes it read plus to right with every successful read/write.
   *(i.e. if position indicator is at 0 position it will go to position 44 if it reads/writes 44 bytes after a successful read/write.)*

The code below is one of my many approaches with no success:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stoixeia
{
    char e[30];
    char t[5];
    float mo;
    int ilikia;
};


int main(void)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    struct stoixeia st;
    int c;

    if((fptr = fopen("sxoleio","rb+")) == NULL)
        exit(1);

    while((c = fread(&st,sizeof(struct stoixeia),1,fptr)) != EOF)
    {
        fseek(fptr,-44,SEEK_CUR);
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(st.e); i++)
            st.e[i] += 1;
        fwrite(&st,sizeof(struct stoixeia),1,fptr);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
```

*Other unsuccessful approaches:(feof,check for eof inside the loop etc.)*

The only success I had so far was with the code below:

```
    while((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
    {
        fseek(fptr,-1,SEEK_CUR);
        fread(&st,sizeof(struct stoixeia),1,fptr);
        fseek(fptr,-44,SEEK_CUR);
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(st.e); i++)
            st.e[i] += 1;
        fwrite(&st,sizeof(struct stoixeia),1,fptr);
        fseek(fptr,1,SEEK_CUR);
        fseek(fptr,-1,SEEK_CUR);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
```

Using **fgetc()** as the while condition and moving indicator by one byte to the right after the operations and then moving it back by one byte seems to trigger EOF and the program ends with success.

What is the reason for this behavior?

I really want to understand the behavior for this so anything would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On success, `fread()` and `fwrite()` return the number of items read or written. This number equals the number of bytes transferred only when size is 1. If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, **the return value is a short item count (or zero).**

Comment: Use `-sizeof st` instead of `-44`  (also instead of `sizeof(struct stoixeia)`)  Don't use `strlen` (the read may not have properly null terminated the string, instead use `for( size_t i = 0; st.e[i] && i < sizeof st.e; i++ ){`. Compare result of `fread` to 1 instead of EOF

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code, but I think the biggest misconception is the return value of `fread`.  Its return value should not be compared to EOF.  When you reach end of file, `fread` will return a short count.  In this case, that means it will return zero.  Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stoixeia {
    char e[30];
    char t[5];
    float mo;
    int ilikia;
};

static void die(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        FILE *fptr;
        struct stoixeia st;
        size_t c;
        const char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "sxoleio";

        if( (fptr = fopen(path, "rb+")) == NULL ){
                die(path);
        }
        while( (c = fread(&st, sizeof st, 1, fptr)) == 1 ){
                if( fseek(fptr, -sizeof st, SEEK_CUR) == -1 ){
                        die("fseek");
                }
                for( size_t i = 0; st.e[i] && i < sizeof st.e; i++ ){
                        st.e[i] += 1;
                }
                if( fwrite(&st, sizeof st, 1, fptr) != 1 ){
                        die("fwrite");
                };
        }
        if( fclose(fptr) ){
                die("fclose");
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But, it's probably cleaner to skip the seeks completely and use two different file handles.  Something like:

```
if( (rf = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL) {
        die(path);
}
if( (wf = fopen(path, "r+")) == NULL) {
        die(path);
}
while( (c = fread(&st, sizeof st, 1, rf)) == 1) {
        for( size_t i = 0; st.e[i] && i < sizeof st.e; i++ ){
                st.e[i] += 1;
        }
        if( fwrite(&st, sizeof st, 1, wf) != 1 ){
                die("fwrite");
        };
}
```

Comment: I tried your first approach but it ended up in an infinite loop again, so I tried the second one and it worked as expected.
About the behavior I read somewhere that a side effect of calling **fseek()** is EOF indication on the file gets cleared if it was a successful call so since the file is open with **"rb+"** it means that fseek will always be succesful so maybe that's the case?
 @William Pursell

Comment: @SpirosGkogkas I don't think you have an infinite loop when in the first case.  What I suspect is happening instead is that the input file has some data at the end (its size is not a multiple of the struct size) and you are blocking on  a read.  Try changing the loop to `while( fread(&st + i++, 1, 1, fptr)) == sizeof st ){` or similar to handle the final short read.

Comment: Note, my previous comment only makes sense if you're not reading from a regular file (eg, a named pipe).  How are you determining that you have an infinite loop?